# Django ListView: filter history based on chosen user

Tags: python, django, listview, filtering, django-crispy-forms

I've got a History ListView in which I'd like to let my Users filter the Historyitems based on which User they picked in the ModelChoiceFields I'm providing them

My History View looks like this:

```py
class HistoryItems(ListView):
    model = HistoryItem
    template_name = 'history/history_table.html'
    context_object_name = 'history_items'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.get('user_id')

        query = {}

        if user_id:
            user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
            query['changed_by'] = user
        else:
            user = None

        history_items = HistoryItem.objects.filter(**query).select_related('changed_by',
                                                                           'content_type')

        return {
            'filter_history_form': HistoryFilterForm(user_id=user_id),
            'history_items': history_items,
        }
```

It returns me the correct History items in a big table (see html below). And then I've got this form:

```py
class HistoryFilterForm(forms.Form):
    normal_user = forms.ModelChoiceField(User.objects.filter(special=None), label="Normal Users", empty_label="All normal users")
    special_user = forms.ModelChoiceField(User.objects.exclude(special=None), label="Special User", empty_label="All special users")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id')
        super(HistoryFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['normal_user'].initial = user_id
        self.fields['special_user'].initial = user_id

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.label_class = 'sr-only'
        self.helper.add_layout(Layout(
            Row(
                Div('normal_user', css_class='col-sm-3'),
                Div('special_user', css_class='col-sm-3'),
            )
        ))
```

This form simply creates two ModelChoiceFields of the same User object, just that one field shows all "normal" users and the other all "special users"

My Urls looks lime this:

```py
urls = [
    path('', views.HistoryItems.as_view(), name='history_index'),
    path('u=<int:pk>', views.HistoryItems.as_view(), name='history_index'),
]
```

I figured that I would need to refresh my page all the time when I'm searching for the history items of another user, which I'm doing with JavaScript (see HTML below). I'm also setting the id of the user in the url as an extra parameter.

And finally my HTML:

```
{% block extra_js %}
    {{ block.super }}

    <script type="application/javascript">

    $(function(){


        var historyUrlBase = '/history/';

        var getParams = function(){
            return {
                'normalUserId': $('#id_normal_user').val(),
                'specialUserId': $('#id_special_user').val()
            }
        };

        var getNormalUrl = function(){
            var params = getParams();
            return historyUrlBase + 'u=' + params.normalUserId;
        };

        $('#id_normal_user').change(function(){
            window.location.href = getNormalUrl();
        });

        var getSpecialUrl = function(){
            var params = getParams();
            return historyUrlBase + 'u=' + params.specialUserId;
        };

        $('#id_special_user').change(function(){
            window.location.href = getSpecialUrl();
        });

    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

   {% crispy filter_history_form %}

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Changed at</th>
                <th>Object</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Changed by</th>
                <th>Difference</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for history_item in history_items %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ history_item.changed_at|date:"d.m.Y h:i:s" }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ history_item.object }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if history_item.action == 'custom' %}
                        {{ history_item.description }}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ history_item.get_action_display }}
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ history_item.changed_by }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ history_item.difference|default:'' }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

My main problem right now is that in my View the kwargs I am receiving are always an empty dict with which ofc nothing works.

But I don't know how I can receive the ID from the users I'm picking, my form always shows the correct users in the two ModelChoiceFields, but how can I get the ID's from those users to use them in my view?

The users themselves only distinguish by the `special` field they have, but they share the same model.

I'm using Django 2.2 and Python 3.7 btw, so maybe if there is an even easier way someone knows, that would also be welcome!

I hope someone knows a good solution or can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in regard! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The kwargs dictionary in get_context_data contains any key word arguments defined in your urls.

```
urls = [
    path('', views.HistoryItems.as_view(), name='history_index'),
    path('u=<int:pk>', views.HistoryItems.as_view(), name='history_index'),
]
```

Your first url has no key word arguments defined. Your second url has one key word argument, pk (i.e. not user_id). So your code should actually be

```
user_id = kwargs.get('pk')
```

**Long Answer**

The way you've set up your form isn't typically how you would handle filtering of data. What you want to do is to submit your form using a GET request.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#get-and-post

Which will produce a url with query string parameters that looks something like

```
/history/?normal_user=1&special_user=1
```

You can then access these query string parameters in your view via the GET dictionary from the request object.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    normal_user = self.request.GET.get('normal_user')
    special_user = self.request.GET.get('special_user')

    # filter your history with normal_user/special_user
```

And finally, delete your second url as this is no longer necessary.